# How does SPARK read data and manage in Memory

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Can anyone please help me understanding how does SPARK read hdfs data and manage it in main memory?

In other words,

If I create 3 RDD, first RDD from hadoop file and do some transformation on it and create a second RDD and again do some transformation on the 2nd RDD and create a 3rd RDD then call some action on 3rd RDD.

1. How many times data will be read from hdfs?
2. Will all three RDD data stay in Memory if we don't call the cache or persist explicitly? i.e. when an action is executing on the 3rd RDD that time whether 1st RDD data remains in memory

Comment: RDD is lazy. Transformational operations do not read any HDFS data

Comment: But i am performing some action on 3rd RDD, So after performing action data will be read from HDFS right ?

Comment: Yes, but only once if all three RDD are acting on the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all RDD share one file, data will only be read once on the action, not on any transformation.

The DAG to regenerate the third RDD will be in memory, since as mentioned, only RDD #3 will contain any actual data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.one more query i am i having if in case i can another action on RDD #3 in that case whether Spark reads data from HDFS or from memory .

Comment: Once you have read the data once, there's no reason to read it again, but we'd have to see your code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't cache RDD3 then Spark will read data from HDFS otherwise it will read from memory.